# windows hot key to invoke application

Tags: windows, winforms, com, win32-process

I have created a windows form application and want to invoke it using hot keys (any combination). But it should be registered at the time of installing the application.

Work around is there to add a global hook to capture all the keyboard events and launch application when the combo is hit. (Dont want to do that) Any other alternatives ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Wouldn't a simple shortcut be sufficient enough?

Comment: IShellLink.SetHotKey().  This is not appropriate, it should be the user's choice and you'll very easily inconvenience him by destroying the hotkey for another app.

Comment: Application is more like a snipping tool, so want it to be present globally. 

Also if i use IShellLink.SetHotKey() then i need to run my app once before it registers the hotkey. Is there no way i can do it while the installation ?

Comment: You can add a script in your msi that executes after installation that creates that shortcut with hotkey by calling
var objShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell");
objShell.CreateShortcut()